# How to do strcmp correctly?

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcmp, getchar

I have to compare the string "death" to to any five character string in a text file.

I can't seem to get my function to work but I can't see what I am doing wrong.  Anyone have any suggestion?

*Notes: my strcmp returns only -1 or 1 but never 0

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

//Function to check if strings are a match regardless of case
bool doesMatch (char testText[], char testDeath[]) {
 if (strcasecmp(testDeath, testText) == 0) {
      return true;
 }
 else
      return false;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
 char test1[5] = {getchar(), getchar(), getchar(), getchar(), getchar()};
 bool testMatch;
 char test2[5] = {'d','e','a','t','h'};

 //Test arrays until End of FIle
 while (test1[4] != EOF) {

      testMatch = doesMatch(test1, test2);
      if (testMatch == true) {
           printf ("Match!\n");
      }

      //"slide" array down one character
      test1[0] = test1[1];
      test1[1] = test1[2];
      test1[2] = test1[3];
      test1[3] = test1[4];
      test1[4] = getchar();

 }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcmp()` can only compare null terminated strings.

Comment: if you are using `testMatch == true`, I believe this should be tagged as C++, not C.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "my strcmp returns only -1 or 1 but never 0"? You implemented your own strcmp and it should return 0 but doesn't?

Comment: @cacho stdbool is part of C99

Comment: Anyway, it seems to be working for me. Precisely what input are you giving that's not working?

Comment: @Kevin The OP means that the *call* to strcmp (actually strcasecmp) always returns -1 or 1 but never 0. It's not hard to understand why.

Comment: @Kevin "it seems to be working for me" -- The behavior is undefined, so the fact that it sometimes works isn't relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Havenard said, strcmp() requires null-terminated strings, which means each string needs to end with the character `'\0'`. If you insist on piecing the strings together yourself, you have to remember to append that null character at the end of each one in order to perform string functions on them.

Comment: Thank you @Havenard and Parker Kemp.  I forgot to add the '\0' character.  You just solved 2 hours of frustration for me.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments to `strcmp` must be terminated by NUL. The simplest change to your current code would be to make your arrays 6 chars long instead of 5, and initialize the sixth char with 0 or '\0'. Or, you could call `strncasecmp` with a length of 5, which will also avoid the undefined behavior of accessing the 6th char of your arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a good reason to leave off the terminating `'\0'` for your inputs, you may use [`strncasecmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncasecmp) instead:

```
bool doesMatch (char testText[], char testDeath[], size_t n) {
     return strncasecmp(testDeath, testText, n) == 0;
}

/*...*/
    testMatch = doesMatch(test1, test2, 5);
```